# How to change Multilevel Menu dropdown icon when input type is checked?

Tags: html, css

I have created a multilevel dropdown menu using css only.
It has a dropdown icon beside the `li` element which has children.

Suppose when I clicked on the **Featured news**  i want to change the **menu-down.png**  icon.

I know it can be done using `input` element `::checked` property but somehow I couldn't do it.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated">
  <li class="has-children">
     <input type="checkbox" name ="group-1" id="group-1">
     <label for="group-1">
        <span class="menu-option-img"><img src="img/menu-cat.png"  ></span>
        <span class="menu-option-content has-dropdown">Featured News</span>
     </label>
     <ul>
        <li class="has-children">
           <input type="checkbox" name ="sub-group-1" id="sub-group-1">
           <label for="sub-group-1">
             <span class="menu-option-img"><img src="img/menu-cat.png"  ></span>
             <span class="menu-option-content has-dropdown">Sub 1</span>
           </label>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#0"><img src="img/menu-cat.png"  > Menu 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#0"><img src="img/menu-cat.png"  > Menu 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#0"><img src="img/menu-cat.png"  > Menu 3</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
    .menu-down {
    height: 7px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    left: 8px !important;
    top: -4px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    }


    .cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked .has-dropdown::after{
        content: "";
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(../img/menu-down.png);
    background-size: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 4px;
    left: 24px;
    }


    .has-dropdown::after {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: url(../img/menu-down.png);
    background-size: 15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 4px;
    left: 24px;
    }

    .cd-accordion-menu {
    margin: auto;
    }
    .cd-accordion-menu ul {
     /* by default hide all sub menus */
    display: none;
    }
    .cd-accordion-menu li {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
    }
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox] {
  /* hide native checkbox */
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.cd-accordion-menu label, .cd-accordion-menu a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 17px 4px 10px 24px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #373737;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.no-touch .cd-accordion-menu label:hover, .no-touch .cd-accordion-menu a:hover {
  background: #52565d;
}
.cd-accordion-menu label::before, .cd-accordion-menu label::after, .cd-accordion-menu a::after {
  /* icons */
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


.cd-accordion-menu img {
    min-width: auto;
    height: 21px;
    margin-right: 18px;
}

.cd-accordion-menu label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*
.cd-accordion-menu label::before, .cd-accordion-menu label::after {
  background-image: url(../img/cd-icons.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
*/
.cd-accordion-menu label::before {
  /* arrow icon */
  left: 18px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
.cd-accordion-menu label::after {
  /* folder icons */
  left: 41px;
  background-position: -16px 0;
}
.cd-accordion-menu a::after {
  /* image icon */
  left: 36px;
  background: url(../img/cd-icons.svg) no-repeat -48px 0;
}
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  /* rotate arrow */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  /* show open folder icon if item is checked */
  background-position: -32px 0;
}
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + ul,
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:nth-of-type(n) + ul {
  /* use label:nth-of-type(n) to fix a bug on safari (<= 8.0.8) with multiple adjacent-sibling selectors*/
  /* show children when item is checked */
  display: block;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul label,
.cd-accordion-menu ul a {
    background: #fff;
    padding-left: 49px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.no-touch .cd-accordion-menu ul label:hover, .no-touch
.cd-accordion-menu ul a:hover {
  background: #3c3f45;
}
.cd-accordion-menu > li:last-of-type > label,
.cd-accordion-menu > li:last-of-type > a,
.cd-accordion-menu > li > ul > li:last-of-type label,
.cd-accordion-menu > li > ul > li:last-of-type a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul label::before {
  left: 36px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu ul a::after {
  left: 59px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul label,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul a {
  padding-left: 68px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::before {
  left: 54px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul a::after {
  left: 77px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a {
  padding-left: 118px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::before {
  left: 72px;
}
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::after,
.cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a::after {
  left: 95px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .cd-accordion-menu label, .cd-accordion-menu a {
    padding: 24px 24px 24px 82px;
    font-size: 1.9rem;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu label::before {
    left: 24px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu label::after {
    left: 53px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul label,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul a {
    padding-left: 106px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul label::before {
    left: 48px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul label::after,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul a::after {
    left: 77px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul label,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul a {
    padding-left: 130px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::before {
    left: 72px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul label::after,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul a::after {
    left: 101px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a {
    padding-left: 154px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::before {
    left: 96px;
  }
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul label::after,
  .cd-accordion-menu ul ul ul a::after {
    left: 125px;
  }
}
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated

Comment: please save this code on jsfiddle or somewhere editor and show us the demo, then only we can easily edit on that editor fix your issue quickly

Answer (score 1):

seems like you forgot to add an adjacent selector "+ label " in the line:

```
 .cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked .has-dropdown::after{
    content: "";    
 }
```

must be:

```
.cd-accordion-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked + label .has-dropdown::after{
    content: "";    
 }
```

Comment: I have made this silly mistake.. Thanks a ton for helping me out :)